# Java 8 Get full URL path without last segment (with or without trailing slash)

Tags: java

I have URLs as below and need to trim them as follows without the last segment. *There may or may not be a trailing slash.*

`localhost:8080/myapp`  -> `localhost:8080/`

`https://myapp-dev.myhost.com/app/` -> `https://myapp-dev.myhost.com/`

`https://myapp-dev.myhost.com/app/app2` -> `https://myapp-dev.myhost.com/app/`

Of course I could try solutions like

`String[] tokens = uri.split("/"); // then concatenate previous ones...`

or

```
Path path = Paths.get(uri.getPath());
String secondToLast = path.getName(path.getNameCount() - 2).toString();
```

But isn't there some more robust utility or method?

Comment: You can use Regex to do split and get the portion.

Comment: Specific Regex suggestions from the gurus are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need is to trim everything after the last "/" (or the second last if the string ends with "/") may be a simple function could solve this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){ 

    Function<String,String> trimUrlString = s -> { 
        s = s.endsWith("/") ? s.substring(0, s.length()-1) : s;
        return  s.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    };

    String u1 = "localhost:8080/myapp";        
    System.out.println(trimUrlString.apply(u1));
    String u2 = "https://myapp-dev.myhost.com/app/";     
    System.out.println(trimUrlString.apply(u2));        
}
//output: localhost:8080/      https://myapp-dev.myhost.com/
```

**EDIT**

Another aproach which might be shorter is to chain two replaceAll calls :

```
myString.replaceAll("/$", "").replaceAll("/[^/]+$", "/");
```

The first call will remove a forward slash at the end if any, if there is no slash at the end `myString` remains the same. The second call will then replace every char after the last `/` which is not a `/`

Some test cases with your examples:

```
    String[] urls = {"localhost:8080/myapp",
                     "https://myapp-dev.myhost.com/app/test.pdf",
                     "http://myapp-dev.host.com/app/", 
                     "http://app.host.com:8080/app/app2"};

    for(String url : urls){
        String s = url.replaceAll("/$", "").replaceAll("/[^/]+$", "/");
        System.out.println(url);
        System.out.println(s); 
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: Was hoping to avoid this indexOf but looks like nothing else is as reliable. thanks

Comment: @geneb. You're welcome. I've edited my answer. May be the second aproach is a bit shorter.

Answer (score 3):

Try passing the url string into a URL object and then pulling out the required segments:

```
URL someURL = new URL("https://myapp-dev.myhost.com/app/");
System.out.println("PATH = " + someURL.getPath());
System.out.println("HOST = " + someURL.getHost());
System.out.println("PROTOCOL = " + someURL.getProtocol());
System.out.println("PORT = " + someURL.getPort());
```

output:

PATH = /app/

HOST = myapp-dev.myhost.com

PROTOCOL = https

PORT = 8080

Comment: Thanks but I lose the port:
`http://localhost:8080/app` --> `localhost` with HOST

Comment: this will throw exception on localhost:8080/myapp because URL requires schema. In URI schema is optional (but still don't match your case). OP might be better off with a regex

Comment: True, a MalformedURLException will be thrown if no protocol is defined.

Comment: There's some other problems with this: Let's say I don't just need the first term, I need *all* terms prior to the last one. Like `http://myapp.host.com/part1/part2/`.  I still want everything before `part2`.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string using a regular expression as I have mentioned in the comment.
I provide below the Regex.

```
^https?:\/\/\w+(:[0-9]*)?(\.\w+)?
```

You can try with the following examples.

https://mydomain:8080

http://localhost:8090

You can also verify in https://rubular.com/ by pasting the regular expression and the example strings.

Comment: Thanks, however these strings don't match correctly to the last segment.
`http://myapp-dev.host.com/app/`, `http://app.host.com:8080/app/app2`

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.lastIndexOf` and `String.substring` to strip off last component.

Something like:

```
private String stripLastComponent(String path) {
    int n = path.lastIndexOf('/');
    if(n < 0) { // no / in path
        return path;
    }
    String stripped = path.substring(0, n);
    if(n == path.length()) { // '/' was last char, so try stripping again
        stripped = stripLastComponent(stripped);
    }
    return stripped;
}
```